# Count() can be used in the "where" for delimiter records with value > Number,

Tags: sql, count

```
SELECT   numero_documento,COUNT(*) AS cuantos
FROM dbo.PERSONAL 
GROUP BY numero_documento 
order by cuantos desc ;
```

I need only records with value of `"Cuanto" >  1`

Comment: Add `Having COUNT(*) > 1` after the group by.  This is pretty basic question.  You might want to delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add having to the query

```
SELECT   numero_documento,COUNT(*) AS cuantos
FROM dbo.PERSONAL GROUP BY numero_documento 
having count(numero_documento) > 1
order by cuantos desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is helpful to see another way to do something.  I'm not claiming this way to be better, but it works.

Use a Sub Query like this

```
Select * from
(
  SELECT   numero_documento,COUNT(*) AS cuantos
  FROM dbo.PERSONAL 
  GROUP BY numero_documento 
) G1
WHERE cuantos > 1
order by cuantos desc
```